# Returning user data using facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to figure out the basics of the facebook php sdk. I'm using the pretty simple code below...

```
<?php

include 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "my_id";
$app_secret = "my_secret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,

));


$userId = $facebook->getUser();

echo $userId;

$userInfo = $facebook->api("/$userId"); 

echo $userInfo['name'];

?>
```

When I ask for the $userId with

```
$userId = $facebook->getUser();

echo $userId;
```

I get the correct value. However when I try to take the next step and retrieve the logged in user's name with :

```
$userInfo = $facebook->api("/$userId"); 

echo $userInfo['name'];
```

nothing is returned. Does anyone see my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`'/$userId'` will actually use the literal string `/$userId`. You probably want `"/$userId"` or `'/me'`